# How can i add a category list in Wordpress (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm searching all over Google for the simple php code that can display the categories on my Wordpress blog. I managed to delete that line and I can't fint it again. I could only find the code for the archive, and here it is:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=12'); ?>
```

Now how can i get it for the categories?

So if anyone could help me on this one I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you're looking for: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories ?